# How to get height of image-containing DIV in $(document).ready() consistently (problem in Webkit only)

Tags: jquery, webkit

I have this fragment that demonstrates the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>height query demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="opts" style="font-size:24px; text-align: center; margin: 10px auto;">
    <div>
      <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif"
           alt="jquerylogo"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Demo of querying height</h1>
  <p>The source code of this document has a DIV prior to the H1.  The DIV contains a
  subdiv which in turn contains an image.<br />
  Using jQuery's <tt>$(document).ready</tt>, the following processing takes place:</p>
<ol><li>DIV queried for its height</li>
  <li>DIV detached from the document</li>
  <li>height value written out here: 
    <span style="font-size: larger; color: magenta;" id="hytmsg"/></li>
  <li>DIV attached at end of document</li></ol>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hyt = $('#opts').height();
    var div_for_later = $('#opts').detach();
    $('#hytmsg').text(''+hyt);
    $('body').append(div_for_later);
  });
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Load it in Opera or Gecko and the number in list item 3 is something sensible like 53.
Load it in a Webkit browser (Chrome 12 on my Windows machine, or Tear, built on an old Webkit version, on my Nokia N800), and the number is 0.

Problem doesn't occur if the content of the subdiv is not an image, or if the image is a direct child of the main div (i.e. no subdiv).  It does occur even if the page and image are both from file: URLs (i.e., not dependent on network lag).

What's a simple change I can make to get that height value correctly on page load, but keep the DIV structured as is?

Comment: Note that there's no need to put your Javascript at the bottom of the page, it can go after the HEAD tag (don't know if there's a performance difference but since Webkit compiles javascript while page is loading, it may affect performance)

Comment: I had read not long ago that, particularly for document-ready style scripts, putting them at the end is considered better practice.  Most of the script tags in my live page _are_ in the HEAD; I just have a small one at BODY end that calls the various initializing functions.

Comment: Always put your JS at the bottom of the page to make the page load faster. Unless you have to execute a script right now, you most of the time will use $(document).ready to wait for the DOM load, so that means you can write them after all the html markup anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var hyt = $('#opts').height();
    var div_for_later = $('#opts').detach();
    $('#hytmsg').text(''+hyt);
    $('body').append(div_for_later);
  });
```

Because `$(document).ready()` only checks for all DOM elements to have been created, while `$(window).load()` actually trigger when all page content has been loaded, including images.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Ready specifically fires prior to images being loaded, therefore they are not loaded when your script runs.

You can use `$(window).load(function () {`  instead of ready.

Answer (score 0):

Add a height value to the img tag via either the style attribute, or CSS.

Comment: That works too, but creates a small maintenance problem if I ever change my image, I need to change the source as well.