# Variables in jquery function not ready ontime for a selector function

Tags: jquery

I am 100% fresh to jQuery. I just learned how to declare variables and am confused as to why this works sometimes and why it does not. When I load a page the `$(".slider").slideshow({` part of my code is supposed to turn a set of `<img>` tags into a slider. Sometimes when I load my page it works but if I hit refresh it does not work most of the time. The slider navigation buttons are shown but the image is no where to be found. I assume it's because for whatever reason, my imageWidth and imageHeight are not being set ontime for the slider function. How could I get this to work every single time?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var imageWidth = $('#imageWidth').width()
    var imageHeight = $('#imageWidth').height()

    $(".slider").slideshow({
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight,
        transition: 'bar'
    });
});
```

Comment: Wait until the window load event, otherwise your images may or may not have a width/height. (looking for dupe)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get height of image-containing DIV in $(document).ready() consistently (problem in Webkit only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475012/how-to-get-height-of-image-containing-div-in-document-ready-consistently-p)

Comment: @KevinB woot woot got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as stated by Kevin B in the comments was that I needed a way to wait for the images to load before getting their height and width. jQuery has a function for that.

[The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded.](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imageWidth').load(function () {
        var imageWidth = $('#imageWidth').width()
        var imageHeight = $('#imageWidth').height()

        $(".slider").slideshow({
            width: imageWidth,
            height: imageHeight,
            transition: 'bar'
        });
    });
```