# How to make page elements clear a fixed-to-top fluid image when the screen is at different sizes?

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid image `width: 100%` fixed to the top of my page. When a user scrolls down the page the text scrolls over the image. See this jsfiddle for a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhs6h/5/show) and my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/qhs6h/5/). This is what I want to happen.

The problem I'm having is when the user has not scrolled yet (i.e. on page load) and browser is a certain width, the image isn't cleared by the page text (the page text overlaps the image). How do I ensure my page text clears the image at all screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting it right you want to set a gap between image and text. When you position element using `fixed` or `absolute` you take out it from normal element grid. If you want to visually separate header image and text add [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to `<content>` and set `padding-top` of it equal to image height. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rebornlab/qhs6h/12/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Take a look at your example in a larger browser window: http://jsfiddle.net/rebornlab/qhs6h/12/show/

Comment: I forgot to mention that according to fact that image is responsive you must set padding always equal to its height. That's the main problem with this case. You could use some javascript (JQuery) to get things right, [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/rebornlab/qhs6h/14/)

Comment: This is 99% perfect aside from the text now scrolls underneath the image. I actually need it to scroll over the top of the image

Comment: Ok, so add `position: relative` and `z-index: 9` to `<content>` to get it above the image. Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rebornlab/qhs6h/16/)

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I'd suggest using `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()` due to a problem in Chrome that has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475034/1709033

Answer (score 0):

apply the css:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

to the header element instead of the image.

check out this jsfiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/SNAG12/qhs6h/6/show/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't work. The text now scrolls behind the image which I don't want. I need it to scroll over the top of the image