# Calculate div height after appendChild without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, appendchild

on my private homepage http://www.alexanderhauck.com/ I'm using appendChild to add multiple images into a div container. The container is set up simply with

```
<div id="instafeed" class="grau">
    <h2 class="ueberschrift">
        Neueste Instagram Fotos
    </h2>
    <br clear="all" />
</div>
```

I'd expect the container to grow in height, so that the background covers the complete area behind the images which I append in a loop with

```
document.getElementById('instafeed').appendChild(img);
```

Instead, the div returns a height of 116. 
[screenshot shows how background stops after 116px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK79H.png)
More precisely, I tried reading various properties with console output:

```
document.getElementById("instafeed").offsetHeight;
-> 116

document.getElementById("instafeed").clientHeight;
-> 116

document.getElementById("instafeed").style.height;
-> ""

document.getElementById("instafeed").clientHeight;
-> 116
```

...but none returns the real height of the div. Did I miss something here? As far as I could see by googling and searching here, most solutions depend on jquery - but how would you solve that issue without? 
Any help is appreciated and best case your ideas are free of jquery - I try to use plain javascript there.
Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Are you using `img` tag or using css background ? It is important to consider he timing of the function execution i.e. when you are trying to access the height of the wrapper..

Comment: May be this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475012/how-to-get-height-of-image-containing-div-in-document-ready-consistently-p) helpful

Comment: Rayon, I'm using CSS background for the wrapping DIV, generated Code of the Script is e.g. <div id="instafeed" class="grau">
  <h2 class="ueberschrift">
   Neueste Instagram Fotos
  </h2>
  <br clear="all">
 <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11248910_754486117993904_1000073030_n.jpg" title="Instagram Foto: #motorcycle in #oldtown #pula" alt="#motorcycle in #oldtown #pula next to a #coffeebar #sign in front of a #graffiti #spraypaint wall." onclick="location.href='https://instagram.com/p/4qkIKAE6I-/'"></div>

Comment: ...the DIV has following CSS properties: .grau {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}